# Under what conditions does "Eval cbv delta in" expand a definition in Coq?

Tags: coq, evaluation

In Proof General (with Coq 8.5), I executed the following:

```
Require Import Arith.
Eval cbv delta in Nat.add_comm 3 7.
```

The output is

> ```
> Nat.add_comm 3 7 : 3 + 7 = 7 + 3
> ```

However, `Print Nat.add_comm.` gives a long and complicated function taking two nats as input. I expected my code to expand the definition of `Nat.add_comm`, which is what `Eval cbv delta in _.` does in similar situations. As a beginner, I know there is a naive misconception lurking. What am I missing?

Comment: Probably it's just that `Nat.add_comm` is opaque - if you went through its proof (and the proofs of dependent lemmas) and replaced `Qed.` with `Defined.` everywhere, it would presumably evaluate to `eq_refl`.

Comment: @DanielSchepler : Thank you. The opaque versus transparent distinction is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding a bit on Daniel's comment, `cbv delta` will unfold an identifier if

1. it has a body (i.e., is not a context variable, axiom, field in a module argument to the current module functor, bound variable, etc.), and
2. it's body was given transparently, i.e., either the proof script was closed with `Defined` rather than `Qed` or the body was given via `:=` or the automatic obligation tactic (for `Program Definition`) or typeclass resolution (for `Instance`s without a body), and
3. it has not been marked opaque via `Opaque id` or `Strategy opaque [id]`, and
4. it was not created by "module-locking" another constant, i.e., defined within a module (or module functor) with a module-type ascription via `:` rather than `<:` (exception: if the module type itself provides the body for the constant)

Note that, at present, `vm_compute` can get around 3 (and the unification engine can too, but `compute`, `lazy`, `cbv`, `hnf`, `cbn` (usually), `simpl` (usually), and `red` cannot), but nothing will get around the others.